# 3D scatter animation does not plots points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm reusing a code that works for 2D animations but I cant tweak it to work in 3D, it just plots the first point and does nothing.

```py
def func(x, y):
    return np.cos(x)*np.sin(y)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
fig.tight_layout()
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = func(X, Y)
# 
ax = Axes3D(fig, computed_zorder=False)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="coolwarm", alpha=0.6)
x_ticks = [0, np.pi/2, np.pi, 3*np.pi/2, 2*np.pi]
x_labels = ["0", "π/2", "π", "3π/2", "2π"]
y_ticks = [0, np.pi/2, np.pi]
y_labels = ["0", "π/2", "π"]
z_ticks = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0]
z_labels = ["0", "1", "0", "-1", "0"]
ax.set_xticks(x_ticks, x_labels)
ax.set_yticks(y_ticks, y_labels)
ax.set_zticks(z_ticks, z_labels)
ax.set_title("cos(x)*sin(y)")
ax.grid(False)
# Gradiente
paso = 1
x_Coord = [0.4*np.pi]
y_Coord = [0.2*np.pi]
z_Coord = [func(x_Coord[0], y_Coord[0])]
gradF = [-0.5590, 0.25, func(-0.5590, 0.25)]
for n in range(3):
    x_Coord.append(x_Coord[n] + paso*(gradF[0]))
    y_Coord.append(y_Coord[n] + paso*(gradF[1]))
    z_Coord.append(z_Coord[n] + paso*(gradF[2]))
#GIF
scat_1 = ax.scatter(x_Coord[0], y_Coord[0], z_Coord[0], c="black", s=50)
def animate(i):
    scat_1.set_offsets((x_Coord[i], y_Coord[i], z_Coord[i]))
    return scat_1
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(z_Coord))
writer = animation.PillowWriter(fps=1)
ani.save("Imagenes/gradiente1.gif", writer=writer)
plt.show()
```

My gif looks like this:
[image]

But it should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3D scatter plot animations, you need to use `Axe._offsets3d = (x,y,z)`. For some reason (related to the backend sorting the variables for performance reasons), `x`, `y`, `z` cannot be floats, so instead of passing `x_Coord[i]` we will pass `x_Coord[i:i+1]` so that it can be a numpy array.

So, your `animate` function should now be:

```py
def animate(i):
    scat_1._offsets3d = (x_Coord[i:i+1], y_Coord[i:i+1], z_Coord[i:i+1])
    return scat_1
```

[image]

Comment: Beware of newcomers  who have not taken the tour and have read nothing on how the site works. IOW, users with absolutely no badges.

Comment: @gboffi Beware in what sense?

Comment: They are not going to accept the soundest, most carefully explained answer in the world. But I'm happy that you answered anyway, as I've learned something (`_offsets3d`) new. Thank you.

Comment: @gboffi whatever 

Comment: @Isaibb ፨ All is well that ends well.